# Android default video player closes when video is done

Tags: java, android, video, android-video-player

I'm using the ACTION_VIEW to stream/play a remote video file.  When the video is done playing the video player closes automatically.  How do I stop the video player from closing? Thanks.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap
            .getFileExtensionFromUrl(scFile.getFileUrl()));

intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(scFile.getFileUrl()), type);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Any solution found ?

Comment: why u want to stop it from closing ? wanna replay or play another video?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this there would need to be a way to pass a "don't close" flag in the intent's data.  I'm not aware that such a flag exists, so if you really need this behavior I think you will need to use the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in another question.

call a new video intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType (uri,"video/mp4");
intent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION, false);

activity.startActivity (intent);
```

link to original question: [Returning to Android app after external video player closes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980102/returning-to-android-app-after-external-video-player-closes)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use it like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri data = Uri.parse("add video url");
intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/mp4");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION,false);
startActivity(intent);
```