# Returning to Android app after external video player closes

Tags: android, video, android-intent

I start a video player from my Android app using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

intent.setDataAndType (uri,"video/mp4");
intent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION, false);

activity.startActivity (intent);
```

This works fine except I do not get back to my app when the user finishes the player using the back button: when finishing the video player, I'm back on the launcher screen - which is not what the user expects.

Any hints what can be done to re-activate my app once the external player finishes? I'm aware I can implement my own player using MediaPlayer and execute the playback within my app, but did not want to start this exercise now.

The MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION makes sure the external video player does not close when reaching the end of the video but has no influence otherwise.

Thanks, Harald

Comment: did you try to pass "true" instead "false"? or to overwrite the "onResume" method?

Comment: Yes, this simply finishes the video player when the end of video is reached. At least when using the standard Video Player in KitKat...

Comment: I think you should use "startActivityForResult" method instead of "startActivity" read here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

Comment: I tried that too, it has no influence for the standard viewer (which seems to not deliver a result when closed). Keep in mind, startActivityForResult requires the intent / activity called to set a result. Furthermore result passing is not directly connected to app / activity reactivation.

Comment: To me it seems more I'm missing a fundamental understanding what makes activities stack when provided as part of different apps. I find the Android concept confusing here.

Comment: I think that when you start activity which is not part of your application, like external video player, your application is onPaused.
it's like when you receive a phone call when you're on Youtube application

Comment: Yes, it is paused, but not restarted.